# Vue Filter To Convert Amount in Numbers to Amount in Words

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using `Laravel 5.7` & `VueJs 2.5.*` ...

I working on Invoice application, while displaying invoice i want my grand total amount to be converted in words. Like this:

**Grand Total In Numbers** = 
`10,000`

**Grand Total In Words** = 
`Ten thousand rupees only`

Is their any Vue Filter or any way to do that ?

**============ I Solved My Problem By Doing This ============**

First i Installed `number-to-words`:

`npm install number-to-words`

In my `app.js` i did this, so i use it globally:

```js
var converter = require('number-to-words');

Vue.filter('toWords', function(value) {
  if (!value) return '';
  return converter.toWords(value);
})
```

Use it in my component like this:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <span>{{ number | toWords }}</span>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: @Andreas already saw these question but not working in my vue component.

Comment: Saif, you need to show your code and what didn't work then.

Comment: @Devon Solved my problem, edited the question with answer, Thanks.